# How do I composite multiple indexed PNGs using python/pillow?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Disclaimer: I am more of an artist than a programmer.

The situation is as follows: I'm building a script to pre-generate assets for a game.
Each finished asset has 5 layers, a background and 4 'part' layers which combined produce completed item art.

However, I would also like to programmatically recolour images from one palette to another. So I built a common 'default' palette usable for all assets and have converted them from RGBA to indexed. But the python script which previously composited them just fine no longer functions and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it to get it to do what it did before.

Specifically, what I am struggling trying to do is to overlay the new images, which are 64x64 indexed PNGs into one combined result and save that in an output folder as it did.

This is the current code:

```
import sys
import os
import time
from glob import glob
from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools

import commonfunctions

try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image

# Generate the image from the supplied paths
def generateImage(gearType, background, layers):
    img = Image.open(background)

    for layer in layers:
        if layer is not None:
            overlayImage = Image.open(layer)
            img.paste(overlayImage, (0,0), overlayImage)

    filename = commonfunctions.generateImageFilename(gearType, background, layers)
    #print("Generated image: " + filename)
    img.save(filename, "PNG")

def generateGearTypeImagesForRarity(gearType, background):
    start = time.time()
    print("Generating all " + gearType + " for " + background)

    # Create output folder
    if not os.path.exists("output/" + gearType):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join('output', gearType))

    layers = commonfunctions.listAllLayers(gearType)

    # Ensure we have 4 layers (even if they are empty)
    while len(layers) < 4:
        layers.append([None])

    # Generate every possible combination of layers for the gear
    for a in layers[0]:
        for b in layers[1]:
            for c in layers[2]:
                for d in layers[3]:
                    # Generate the image passing in each layer
                    generateImage(gearType, background, [a, b, c, d])

    # Print how long it took to do a whole gear type
    print("Generating {} took {:.2f} seconds".format(gearType, time.time()-start))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    startTotal = time.time()

    backgrounds = commonfunctions.listAllBackgrounds()

    # Use 4 cores
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        pool.starmap(generateGearTypeImagesForRarity, itertools.product(commonfunctions.listGearTypes(), backgrounds))

    print("All together it took {:.2f} seconds".format(time.time()-startTotal))
    print('Possibly successful layering!')
```

Here are the errors when I run the code:

```
C:\Users\Hunter\Desktop\pythontesting>python imagebaker.py
Generating all helm for backgrounds\nbg_0.png
Generating all helm for backgrounds\nbg_1.png
Generating all helm for backgrounds\nbg_2.png
Generating all helm for backgrounds\nbg_3.png
Generating all helm for backgrounds\nbg_4.png
Generating all helm for backgrounds\nbg_5.png
Generating all chest for backgrounds\nbg_0.png
Generating all chest for backgrounds\nbg_1.png
Generating all chest for backgrounds\nbg_2.png
Generating all chest for backgrounds\nbg_3.png
Generating all chest for backgrounds\nbg_4.png
Generating all chest for backgrounds\nbg_5.png
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
 "C:\Users\Hunter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\Hunter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 51, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "C:\Users\Hunter\Desktop\pythontesting\imagebaker.py", line 51, in generateGearTypeImagesForRarity
    generateImage(gearType, background, [a, b, c, d])
  File "C:\Users\Hunter\Desktop\pythontesting\imagebaker.py", line 22, in generateImage
    img.paste(overlayImage, (0,0), overlayImage)
  File "C:\Users\Hunter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1525, in paste
    self.im.paste(im, box, mask.im)
ValueError: bad transparency mask
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hunter\Desktop\pythontesting\imagebaker.py", line 63, in <module>
    pool.starmap(generateGearTypeImagesForRarity, itertools.product(commonfunctions.listGearTypes(), backgrounds))
  File "C:\Users\Hunter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 372, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\Hunter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError: bad transparency mask
```

As these are indexed PNGs, I have a single palette entry with max transparency used to border the other colours to display what areas should be transparent or not.
This script does use multithreading to speed things up courtesy of a software engineer friend, but I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: It's very difficult to help when your code is incomplete and we have no idea what your input and output images look like, nor what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've posted the full code as well as what I'm trying to do with it (given a number of input layers, save a combined composite of them)

Comment: Please have a look at the [mre] help section. As-is, there's way too much unnecessary code! Also, I suppose `commonfunctions` is some custom module from you? Nobody has that, thus nobody can run your code. Please break your actual problem down, and solely provide the minimum needed code including a set of images to reproduce the stated behaviour.